# Stuck With Including A Font In My index.html file

Tags: html, css, url, fonts

[image]

A friend of mine is running into this problem. It says it can't use the '|' in the URL. I've never run into this problem. Any help?

Comment: Your friend is running your code through a validator. While the validator is correct it is what google is expecting to find within the request. In this case - ignore the validator

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the image, change the | with its percent-encoding `%7C`.

```
https://font.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One%7COpen+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,800
```